# websocketd: WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed

Tags: php, linux, bash, websocket

I am dealing with websocketd and followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/wiki/Ten-minute-tutorial#a-simple-endpoint). However, when I call my HTML page I get the error in my Edge-Browser:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed:
```

I run the service with SSL and have Snakeooil certificates included

```
  ./websocketd \
    --port=8080 \
    --ssl \
    --sslcert="/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem" \
    --sslkey="/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" \
    --staticdir=. \
    ./count.sh
```

Websocketd seems to run as expected:

```
Wed, 12 Oct 2022 13:07:40 +0200 | INFO   | server     |  | Serving using application   : ./count.sh 
Wed, 12 Oct 2022 13:07:40 +0200 | INFO   | server     |  | Serving static content from : .
Wed, 12 Oct 2022 13:07:40 +0200 | INFO   | server     |  | Starting WebSocket server   : wss://sv2:8080/
Wed, 12 Oct 2022 13:07:40 +0200 | INFO   | server     |  | Serving CGI or static files : https://sv2:8080/
```

**netstat -tulpn**

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      62688/./websocketd
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm a novice http'er so fwiw ... seems odd that your server starts up listening on `sv2:8080` but your error indicates attempting to connect to `127.0.0.1:8080` (aka `localhost:8080`); unless `sv2` is an alias to `localhost/127.0.0.1` I would expect problems connecting